# Play multiple video with Open Gl Es 2.0 android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-video-player, android-videoview

I need to play multiple video on screen using Open Gl ES 2.0 in Android. I have the code of playing a single video. For playing 3 videos I have used three 3 views with 3 videos. However there are issues related to performance when playing 3 videos (there is flickering on the screen at times or video stuck issue). So I wanted to know if there is better way of playing multiple video using Open Gl

When I played those 3 video using VideoView without using Open Gl, they are playing fluently. Even with 4 videos it worked well.

Comment: Hi. Let me know if you need further clarifications regarding the question. I expect some comments and discussions before the question is invalidated or not understood. Please reply

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36742

I have solved the issued from the above link. It says why the flickering of video occurs when displaying a video with texture view.

Thanks all.